# Interpreting Logistic Regression with categorical variable

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, ecology

Please help! I am using binary logistic regression to model the probability of nesting in 5 different habitat types, with 1 = nest presence and 0 = random point. I have 5 different habitat types and want to know which one is most important, or most selected for.

However, I am having trouble interpreting which one is most significant. In the attached model summary it says that Herbaceous has a significant p-value but in this context i think that just means theres significantly more nests in Herbaceous than the reference category (dwarf shrubland habitat). But it doesn't tell me anything regarding whether herbaceous is more selected for than the other habitats listed right? Herbaceous has the most nest points in it out of any habitat (86/205) and is also the smallest habitat type so it would make sense if it was the most significant but I dont know if i can say that statistically.
I am also attaching a screenshot of the odds-ratio interpretation (for some reason i am getting 40 warnings all saying the same thing). Any advice on how to interpret and/or modify the analysis is greatly appreciated; thanks in advance!

```
summary(model3)

Call:
glm(formula = nest_pres ~ Hab_Class + dist_nest, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = nests)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.8165  -0.0567   0.1704   0.4337   3.6930  

                       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)             2.329899   0.394125   5.912 3.39e-09 ***

Hab_ClassHerbaceous     1.914826   0.660165   2.901  0.00373 ** 

Hab_ClassHuman Altered  0.249796   0.556323   0.449  0.65342    
Hab_ClassShrubland      0.191257   0.527073   0.363  0.71670    
Hab_ClassWoodland      -0.771657   0.637839  -1.210  0.22636    
dist_nest              -0.032765   0.004196  -7.808 5.81e-15 ***

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 545.55  on 393  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 177.91  on 388  degrees of freedom
AIC: 189.91

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 8
```

```
#2.2 Interpretation
> library(MASS)
> round(exp(cbind(coef(model3), confint(model3))),3)
Waiting for profiling to be done...
                              2.5 % 97.5 %
(Intercept)            10.277 4.964 23.487
Hab_ClassHerbaceous     6.786 2.002 27.619
Hab_ClassHuman Altered  1.284 0.436  3.917
Hab_ClassShrubland      1.211 0.432  3.469
Hab_ClassWoodland       0.462 0.130  1.615
dist_nest               0.968 0.959  0.975
There were 40 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
3: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

Comment: Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen 
readers can't handle the computer output in your screenshot.  Please include computer output as text!

Comment: my apologies, i have updated the question above to include the R code as text

Comment: Ok but the output is an image, not text.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the estimate for Hab_ClassHerbaceous tells you that Hab_ClassHerbaceous is significantly different from your reference category. Estimates for other levels tell you how these levels differ from dwarf shrubland habitat - not significantly.

(also, dist_nest, presumably a continuous variable, has a significant effect on nest presence).

If I understand correctly, you want to know whether other levels of Hab_Class are different from each other regarding the presence vs. absence of a nest. Your model contains the information about these comparisons too, you just need to extract it. In R, emmeans package is great for that. Try

```
library(emmeans)
em<-emmeans(model3, pairwise ~ Hab_Class, type="response")
em
```

This gives you the estimated marginal means for each Hab_Class level, and each pairwise comparison between the levels with Tukey's p-value adjustment.

The type="response" gives you the marginal means as estimated probabilities of there being a nest in that level of Hab_Class. If you want the means on the logit scale, just leave the type="response" out.

Comment: Ok great thank you for this suggestion!